# Show and hide details on click of a divison

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having  divisons show and hide.Now what i want is that on clicking "show" a divison below it show the details and the text of the "show" divison changes to "hide" and on clicking "hide" the details get hidden and text changes to "show".How this can be done .Please help

Here is my html :

```
     <span id="show" class="" style="text-decoration: underline">
       <a href="#" class="fill-div" style="width: 100px;">
         Show details
        </a>
     </span>

      <span id="hide" class="" style="display:none">
           <a href="#" class="fill-div" style="width: 100px;">
                Hide details
           </a>
       </span>

       <div id="info" style="display:none; margin-left:2em">
       <i>
            Details shown here
       </i>
       </div>
```

EDIT :

```
<tr class="">
            <td width="40%" valign="top">
                (<%=browser%>) 

             <span class="show"  style="text-decoration: underline">
                <a href="#"  class="fill-div" style="width: 100px; margin-left: 141px; margin-top: -20px;">Show details</a>
             </span>

            <div class="info" style="display:none; margin-left:2em">
             <i>
                 "<%=useragent%>"
             </i>
            </div>
            </td>
            <td valign="top">
                 India(<%=rs.getString("IP_ADD")%>)
            </td>
            <td valign="top">
                3:16 pm (0 minutes ago)
            </td>
        </tr>
```

My JAVASCRIPT :

```
            <script>
           $(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.show').click(function() {

        $(this).next().toggle();
        var visible = $(this).next().is(":visible");
if(visible){
  $('a',this).html('Hide details');
}else{
$('a',this).html('Show details');}

    });
});


        </script>
```

It does not display the details.Please help

Comment: why two show hide spans??

Comment: @Sekai The problem am facing is that the details to be shown vary as it is being fetched from database.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar Where two shows ?

Comment: one with id hide and id show.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar If it can be done with one .Then do please help me

Comment: @user3522121: posted the answer below. check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to span for toggling content. using two span for achiving this will make code more complicated. Try this:

**Html**

```
<span id="show" class="" style="text-decoration: underline">
   <a href="#" class="fill-div" style="width: 100px;">
     Show details
    </a>
 </span>
 <div id="info" style="display:none; margin-left:2em">
   <i>
        Details shown here
   </i>
 </div>
```

**Js:**

```
$('#show').click(function() {
 $('#info').toggle();
 var visible = $('#info').is(":visible");
 if(visible)
   $('a',this).html('Hide details');
 else
   $('a',this).html('Show details');
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/APA2S/1785/)**

**update:**

**[Demo for multiple](http://jsfiddle.net/APA2S/1786/)**

Comment: Its working for only first row of table.Please help.Am having multiple show and hide options

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#show a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#info, #hide").show();
    $("#show").hide();
});
$("#hide a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#info, #hide").hide();
    $("#show").show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to show/hide the "Details" div:

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Also, you could use just one span to display the "Show/Hide" link, changing the text accordingly when you click to toggle.

Answer (score 0):

A breeze with jQuery. Try my example on [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/H8gN8/).

```
// Gets executed when document and markup is fully loaded
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Bind a click event on the element with id 'toggle'
    $('#toggle').click(function() {

        // Change text accordingly
        if ($('#text').html() == 'Show details') {
            $('#text').html('Hide details');  
        } else {
            $('#text').html('Show details');  
        }

        // Show / Hide info bar
        $('#info').toggle(); 
    });
});
```

Comment: What if i am having many table rows .This work only with first one.See my edit

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/Mp8p2/

You don't need nearly as much HTML:

```
<span class="toggle">Show Details</span>

<div id="info">
    Details shown here
</div>
```

along with just `display:none` in the css and the following jQuery:

```
$(".toggle").click(function() {
    $('#info').slideToggle();
    if($(this).html() == "Show Details") {
        $(this).empty().text("Hide Details");
    }
    else { 
        $(this).html("Show Details");        
    }
});
```

Comment: Am having multiple show and hide options represented as table rows.It work only for first row of table